# Edit form not loading a form value

Tags: django, django-forms, django-1.4

I have an edit view for one of my models.

```
@login_required        
def edit(request, id):
    ''' Edit form '''
    if id:
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=id)
        if post.user != request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
    else:
        post = Post()

    if request.POST:
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance = post)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('posts_manage'))
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance = post)

    return render_to_response('posts/add.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Everything works fine, all the post information is loaded correctly, but one of the fields, which is a `select` box, is not being selected with the value obtained from the DB. Other select boxes are selected to the appropriate value.

The field that is not being populated properly in the model definition:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    BATHROOM_CHOICES = ((1,'1'),(1.5,'1.5'),(2,'2'),(2.5,'2.5'),(3,'3'),(3.5,'3.5'),(4,'4'), (4.5,'4.5'),(5,'5+'))
    bathrooms = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 2,decimal_places = 1,choices = BATHROOM_CHOICES)
```

Relevant section inside add.html:

```
{{ form.bathrooms|bootstrap}}
```

forms.py

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ('available','user',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        return super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['commit'] = False
        obj = super(PostForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request:
            obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

Comment: What's inside `posts/add.html`?

Comment: a simple {{form.bathrooms|bootsrap}} for that field...

Comment: What is the bootstrap filter? What does it do? Where does it come from?

Comment: it is for the twitter bootstrap stuff... I removed it and was still having the same problem

Comment: Could you post the definition of `PostForm` as well, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data in the DB is not being matched by a choice in `BATHROOM_CHOICES`

`BATHROOM_CHOICES = ((1,'1'),(1.5,'1.5'),(2,'2'),(2.5,'2.5'),(3,'3'),(3.5,'3.5'),(4,'4'), (4.5,'4.5'),(5,'5+'))`
and
`models.DecimalField(max_digits = 2,decimal_places = 1,`
are contradicting.

Your model definition expects all values will have a decimal place of at least 1, and probably coerces values like whole number from `1` to `1.0` in the DB (depending on adapter implementation).

so then when it looks for a choice matching the value `1 !== 1.0` and so no value is selected.

Possible fix:
`BATHROOM_CHOICES = ((1.0,'1'),(1.5,'1.5'),(2.0,'2'),(2.5,'2.5'),(3.0,'3'),(3.5,'3.5'),(4.0,'4'), (4.5,'4.5'),(5.0,'5+'))`

Comment: you are welcome, i started writing a different solution altogether then it dawned on me that it was a typing issue.